# CPack NuGet Warning NU5119 NoDefaultExcludes

Tags: cmake, package, nuget, cpack, nuget-spec

I am trying to create a NuGet package using CPack and want to pack files starting with '.'. I couldn't find any CPack variable to pass option [NoDefaultExcludes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5119). Also there is no variable to modify CPack generated nuspec file to add [file tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files).

Is there a way to resolve this just using CPack?

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find any CPack variable to pass option NoDefaultExcludes.

Yep, the variable is undocumented yet (PR is welcomed %). You can append your options to the `CPACK_NUGET_PACK_ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS` list variable.

> Also there is no variable to modify CPack generated nuspec file to add file tag.

Whatever additional files you want to add to the package, just use the `install(FILES)` signature they gonna be included in a package.